# Google sheets custom function w/ regex fails on alternating rows when used in range

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just wrote up a simple google sheets function to fix some URLs.  This function works fine in a browser, when passed the array of values manually.  When called from google sheets, the function fails for **every other row**.

This isn't a problem with data, since I can make it work for the "failing" rows by moving the formula down one row, or calling it individually for each cell.  I think this may be an issue with `regex` inside google sheets.

```
var pattern = /^http:\/\/(.*\/\d\/.*)_(.*)\/(g\d+p.*)$/ig;

function encode(input) {
  if (!input) return "";
  if (input.map) {
    return input.map(encode);
  } else {
    try {
      // same error happens, at this location, w/ or w/o toString()
      var matches = pattern.exec(input.toString());
      return matches[1] + encodeURIComponent(matches[2]) + matches[3];
    } catch (e) {
      return "error=" + e.message + " value = [" + input + "] ";
    }
  }
}
```

*Edit*: To make things clearer for those who come after, this also fails the same way when the regex is inside the "else" clause:

```
else { 
     var matches = /^(http:\/\/.*\/\d\/.*_)(.*)(\/g\d+p.*)$/ig.exec(input.toString());
     ... continues as normal
```

For alternating rows of the data, I get this error message:

```
error=Cannot read property "1" from null.  value =  [ http://... ]
```

I have tried:

- Putting the regex inside the `try{}`
- Putting the regex inside the `encode{}` function
- Writing two separate functions (one for doing 1 value)

In the failure case I have data like this:

- A1-A8 have URLs in them
- B1 has the formula "=encode(A1:A8)"
- Data in B1, B3, B5, B7 calculate perfectly
- Data in B2, B4, B6, B8 error out (my error message shows up)

Moving the formula to cell "B2" and saying `=encode(A2:A8)` causes all the "failing" rows to calculate and the others to fail!

Comment: you cut off the error message exactly where it gets important, what is the value in `value = [ http://... ]` ?

Comment: Is there a reason to have the global flag in the regex? I'm not sure, but I think it is possible that the regex is executing from the index following the previous match.

Comment: Adam, I'll look into that now.  It is there out of habit, and it works fine *outside* google sheets when I pass in an array :-/

Comment: @funkwurm - the message isn't important.  that value is just the value in the left cell.  the important part of the error messages is the "cannot read property 1 from null" which shows what is crashing.

Comment: @AdamL Please post that as the answer.  Removing the "g" fixed it for me.  Still not totally clear why, or why it was bad bad bad in gsheets but OK in vanilla JS or a chrome console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer (as confirmed by your comment on the OP) is to remove the final "g" (the global flag) from the regex.

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec
>
> **Syntax** regexObj.exec(*str*)
>
> **Parameters** *str* The string against which to match the regular expression.
>
> ...
>
> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec()
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance
>   the lastIndex property).

So it seems you really should only include the global flag when you intend to continue to search for matches in the same string.

As to why it worked in other environments, I'm not sure. Indeed, it seems a bit strange to continue searching from where you left off, *even though you are applying `exec` to an entirely new string*. Perhaps the implementation in GAS is a little bit "off" - someone with more knowledge might be able to comment on this.

Comment: Strangely, this was also what happened when I put pattern INSIDE the `else` block.  Since the function is called once per string, I would think this would make a new regex each time.  I **guess** that an inline regex gets moved out of function scope and re-used.   I was also able to solve it, *inside* the `else`, by replacing `pattern` with `new RegExp("blah")`.

Comment: Odd, I did not know this about `.exec()`. I suppose should you need the `/g` modifier for a different reason, you could do `'string'.match(/your_regex/g);` rather than `/your_regex/g.exec('string');`

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, the error means that `matches` is empty or non-existent, which probably means that the regex did not find a match. So it is important to see whether the value of `input` *should* match or indeed does not conform to the requirements of the regex.

The regex does the following:

```
^http:\/\/(.*\/\d\/.*)_(.*)\/(g\d+p.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dDmXAK4cWksMKfVQ), Matched text:

```
http://whatever/3/some_thing/g4p/can be anything
^^^^^^^        ^^^    ^     ^^^^
```

So if any of the following is not found in the URL, no match will be returned:

- URL does not start with `http://` (but, for instance, *http**s**://*)
- There is no occurrence of: *`/`, a number, `/`*
- There is no `_`
- There is no occurrence of *`/g`, some numbers, `p`*

Are you sure the text meets all these requirements every time?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in the question, but to reiterate: All rows are fine, all text is fine.  Putting the formula in in row 1 causes row 1,3,5 to show the correct value, but 2,4,6 to show the error.  Putting the formula in row 2 causes rows 2,4,6 to show the correct result, but 3,5,7 to show the wrong one. This is something to do with the code running in sheets;  If I run the same function against an array in plain JS, *everything* works fine.

Comment: ... I absolutely love that regex visualizer, especially for helping me teach folks.  I lost the URL a long time ago, nice to have it again!  Thank you for that!

Comment: I did read that yes, but just wanted to absolutely rule out that the input wasn't somehow different than expected when passed into the regex. Sorry if my answer underestimated your regex knowledge, but that happens a lot in the regex tag **;)**